# tar --exclude doesn't exclude. Why?

Tags: tar

I have this very simple line in a bash script which executes successfully (i.e. producing the `_data.tar` file), except that it **doesn't** exclude the sub-directories it is told exclude via the `--exclude` option:

```
/bin/tar -cf /home/_data.tar  --exclude='/data/sub1/*'  --exclude='/data/sub2/*' --exclude='/data/sub3/*'  --exclude='/data/sub4/*'  --exclude='/data/sub5/*'  /data
```

Instead, it produces a `_data.tar` file that contains everything under /data, including the files in the subdirectories I wanted to exclude.

Any idea why? and how to fix this?

**Update** I implemented my observations based on the link provided in the first answer below (top level dir first, no whitespace after last exclude):

```
/bin/tar -cf /home/_data.tar  /data  --exclude='/data/sub1/*'  --exclude='/data/sub2/*'  --exclude='/data/sub3/*'  --exclude='/data/sub4/*'  --exclude='/data/sub5/*'
```

But that didn't help. All "excluded" sub-directories are present in the resulting `_data.tar` file.

This is puzzling. Whether this is a bug in current tar (GNU tar 1.23, on a CentOS 6.2, Linux 2.6.32)  or "extreme sensitivity" of tar to whitespaces and other easy-to-miss typos, I consider this a bug. For now.

**This is horrible**: I tried the insight suggested below (no trailing `/*`) and it still doesn't work in the production script:

```
/bin/tar -cf /home/_data.tar  /data  --exclude='/data/sub1'  --exclude='/data/sub2'  --exclude='/data/sub3'  --exclude='/data/sub4'
```

I can't see any difference between what I tried and what @Richard Perrin tried, except for the quotes and 2 spaces instead of 1. I am going to try this (must wait for the nightly script to run as the directory to be backed up is huge) and report back.

```
/bin/tar -cf /home/_data.tar  /data --exclude=/data/sub1 --exclude=/data/sub2 --exclude=/data/sub3 --exclude=/data/sub4
```

I am beginning to think that all these `tar --exclude` sensitivities aren't tar's but something in my environment, but then what could that be?

**It worked!** The last variation tried (no single-quotes and single-space instead of double-space between the `--exclude`s) tested working. Weird but accepting.

**Unbelievable!** It turns out that an older version of `tar` (1.15.1) would only exclude if the top-level dir is **last** on the command line. This is the exact opposite of how version 1.23 requires. FYI.

Comment: None of these worked for me, until I realized I had to escape the `[` and `]` in the filename of the file I was trying to exclude. Using `\[` and `\]`, even inside of single quotes, was the only way I could get it to work. Worries me that it may exclude other important files this way. Using GNU tar 1.29

Comment: Correction, in my case I needed to use `--no-wildcards`. That took too long to figure out.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you want to exclude an entire directory, your pattern should match that directory, not files within it. Use `--exclude=/data/sub1` instead of `--exclude='/data/sub1/*'`

Be careful with quoting the patterns to protect them from shell expansion.

See this example, with trouble in the final invocation:

```
$ for i in 0 1 2; do mkdir -p /tmp/data/sub$i; echo foo > /tmp/data/sub$i/foo; done
$ find /tmp/data
/tmp/data
/tmp/data/sub2
/tmp/data/sub2/foo
/tmp/data/sub0
/tmp/data/sub0/foo
/tmp/data/sub1
/tmp/data/sub1/foo
$ tar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar /tmp/data --exclude='/tmp/data/sub[1-2]'
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/tmp/data/
/tmp/data/sub0/
/tmp/data/sub0/foo
$ tar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar /tmp/data --exclude=/tmp/data/sub[1-2]
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/tmp/data/
/tmp/data/sub0/
/tmp/data/sub0/foo
$ echo tar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar /tmp/data --exclude=/tmp/data/sub[1-2]
tar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar /tmp/data --exclude=/tmp/data/sub[1-2]
$ tar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar /tmp/data --exclude /tmp/data/sub[1-2]
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/tmp/data/
/tmp/data/sub2/
/tmp/data/sub2/foo
/tmp/data/sub0/
/tmp/data/sub0/foo
/tmp/data/sub2/
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
/tmp/data/sub2/foo
$ echo tar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar /tmp/data --exclude /tmp/data/sub[1-2]
tar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar /tmp/data --exclude /tmp/data/sub1 /tmp/data/sub2
```

Comment: Thanks for the very focused and clear answer. Regarding your 1st point, I was trying to follow the tips in [this LQ thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/tar-exclude%3Ddirectory-455908/). I am not sure what I missed, but now that I read your 2nd point it may very well an absolute vs. relative path issue. I will try that and report back. +1 for now.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is the `--exclude b` (space instead of equal sign) vs. `--exclude=b`. Does this make any difference? (shouldn't IMHO)

Comment: The equal sign can be essential to avoid shell expansion of unquoted patterns. If you have a space instead, then an unquoted pattern can be expanded by the shell into a single --exclude argument, and the remaining expansions give as files to add to the tar file. Your examples above all have '=' - if the script doesn't, and is missing single quotes, then that can the source of your problem.

Comment: OK. I tested your example on my box and it works, even with multiple `--exclude=` on the same line. So the difference must be the idiotic `/*` that I appended to each sub-directory. I will test this tonight in the production script and report back. Another +1.

Comment: For me, the answer from @carlo was the specific problem - stupid tar can't take --exclude as the last option on the command line - obviously causing lots of headaches.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 92):

It may be that your version of `tar` requires that the `--exclude` options have to be placed at the beginning of the `tar` command.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/984204

```
tar --exclude='./folder' --exclude='./upload/folder2' \
    -zcvf /backup/filename.tgz .
```

See: http://mandrivausers.org/index.php?/topic/8585-multiple-exclude-in-tar/

```
tar --exclude=<first> --exclude=<second> -cjf backupfile.bz2 /home/*
```

Alternative:

```
EXCLD='first second third'
tar -X <(for i in ${EXCLD}; do echo $i; done) -cjf backupfile.bz2 /home/*
```

Yet another `tar` command tip is from [here](http://thibauld.com/2010/02/how-to-exclude-multiple-directories-while-creating-an-archive-with-tar/):

```
tar cvfz myproject.tgz --exclude='path/dir_to_exclude1' \
                       --exclude='path/dir_to_exclude2' myproject
```

Comment: See my update above. The last variation tried (no quotes, single space) works. I have no idea why. +1 for the well thought answer + links.

Comment: FYI, under debian, If I dont precise the filter, like `--exclude=mydir/*` then it doesnt work (using `tar --exclude=maindir/mydir/* -cjf archive.tar2.bz2 maindir/*`).

Comment: @OlivierPons rather than "under debian", or perhaps with it, put the version of tar (`tar --version`); debian will presumably ship with many different versions of tar through the years.

Comment: My version (1.29) only works with `--exclude` before `-czf`.

Comment: This was the correct solution for me using zsh, thank you.

Comment: This is exactly why working with shell tools can be a frustrating experience. `man tar` does not give any hints where to place `--exclude`, nor does it explain clearly why the argument position plays a role.

Answer (score 8):

For excluding multiple files, try

```
--exclude=/data/{sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4}
```

This will save some code and headache. This is a global solution, for all kind of programs / options. If you also want to include the parent directory in your selection (in this case data), you have to include a trailing comma. E.g.:

```
umount /data/{sub1,sub2,}
```

Comment: I love curlies.  I find that a lot of people don't know about them, even with years of unix experience.  `mv /very/very/very/very/long/path/to/a/file{,.bak}`

Comment: Note that by not using single quotes around the pattern this method takes advantage of *shell* pattern expansion, creating multiple positional arguments after the `--exclude` flag, instead of passing a glob(3) pattern that `tar` expands. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/problems-with-exclude.html

Comment: Careful, the braces can break bash functions ... unexpected "{"

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it didn't exclude for a different reason.

The full path vs relative path.

Both the exclude and the directory must use the same path format (i.e both full path or both relative paths)

Example:

```
tar -cvf ctms-db-sync.tar --exclude='/home/mine/tmp/ctms-db-sync/sql' ctms-db-sync
```

**This will not work because exclude uses full path where as the target uses a relative path**

```
tar -cvf ctms-db-sync.tar --exclude='/home/mine/tmp/ctms-db-sync/sql' /home/mine/tmp/ctms-db-sync
```

**This works because both use the full path**

```
tar -cvf ctms-db-sync.tar --exclude='ctms-db-sync/sql' ctms-db-sync
```

**This works because both use the relative path**

Comment: Relative path works for me, in older version of tar --exclude=DIR will enough but in newest need to add --exclude=./DIR

Answer (score 5):

This link might be helpful.
http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/739467.html

Two immediate differences between the non-working line and some tips in the link:

1. All excludes come ***after*** the top-level directory.
2. Cannot have ANY spaces after the last `--exclude`.

Comment: Thanks. The answer by `-MAK` caught my attention and so far I have been able to spot the following differences between my non-working line and the following: **1.** All excludes come *after* the top-level directory. **2.** Cannot have ANY spaces after the last `--exclude`. I will test these insights and report back. +1 for now.

Comment: @ateiob If you figure it out, can you post an answer here or edit this one? We generally prefer not having answers that are just links elsewhere

Comment: @Michael Mrozek Absolutely. This is exactly what I wrote in my comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

I am using a mac, and found that excludes weren't working unless the top level folder is the last argument

example of working command:

```
tar czvf tar.tgz --exclude='Music' dir
```

FYI:

```
$: tar --version
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
```

Comment: Same goes with tar 1.27.1 via Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround may be to use a combination of `find ... -prune` and `tar` to exclude the specified directories.

On Mac OS X the `--exclude` option of GNU `tar` seems to work as it should though.

In the following test case the directories `/private/var/log/asl` and `/private/var/log/DiagnosticMessages` are to be excluded from a compressed archive of the `/private/var/log` directory.

```
# all successfully tested in Bash shell on Mac OS X (using gnutar and gfind)

# sudo port install findutils  # for gfind from MacPorts

sudo gnutar -czf ~/Desktop/varlog.tar.gz /private/var/log --exclude "/private/var/log/asl" --exclude "/private/var/log/DiagnosticMessages"

sudo gnutar -czf ~/Desktop/varlog.tar.gz  --exclude "/private/var/log/asl" --exclude "/private/var/log/DiagnosticMessages" /private/var/log

set -f # disable file name globbing
sudo gnutar -czf ~/Desktop/varlog.tar.gz  --exclude "/private/var/log/asl" --exclude "/private/var/log/Diagnostic*" /private/var/log

# combining GNU find and tar (on Mac OS X)

sudo gfind /private/var/log -xdev -type d \( -name "asl" -o -name "DiagnosticMessages" \) -prune -o -print0 | 
   sudo gnutar --null --no-recursion -czf ~/Desktop/varlog.tar.gz --files-from -

# exclude even more dirs
sudo gfind /private/var/log -xdev -type d \( -name "asl" -o -name "[Dacfks]*" \) -prune -o -print0 | 
    sudo gnutar --null --no-recursion -czf ~/Desktop/varlog.tar.gz --files-from -


# testing the compressed archive

gnutar -C ~/Desktop -xzf ~/Desktop/varlog.tar.gz

sudo gfind /private/var/log ~/Desktop/private \( -iname DiagnosticMessages -or -iname asl \)

sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop/varlog.tar.gz ~/Desktop/private
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for the suggestion. At this point I am still trying to understand why a well documented (and mature) feature isn't working in my script, nightly run by cron.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try the command with another option:

```
--wildcards
```

And check if it's running as intended.

Comment: See my update above. The last variation tried (no quotes, single space) works. I have no idea why. +1 for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Just now detected on tar (GNU tar) 1.29

THis call does not exclude from archive files specified with --exclude-from:

```
/bin/tar --files-from ${datafile} --exclude-from ${excludefile} -jcf ${backupfile}
```

This call works coorectly:

```
/bin/tar --exclude-from ${excludefile} --files-from ${datafile} -jcf ${backupfile}
```

Order of parameters is important!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `--exclude=` use `-X` with a text file:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/exclude-certain-files-when-creating-a-tarball-using-tar-command/

Comment: -X was already mentioned in  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33334/39954

Answer (score 1):

Additional notes to [R Perrin's excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33036/188542):

Suppose you do not want to archive absolute but relative paths, e.g. 'data' instead of '/tmp/data'.
To exclude absolute paths your tar arguments will differ based on the tar implementation (gnu tar vs. bsd tar) you use:

```
$ for i in 0 1 2; do
    for j in 0 1 2; do 
      mkdir -p /tmp/data/sub$i/sub$j
      echo foo > /tmp/data/sub$i/sub$j/foo
    done
  done

$ find /tmp/data/
/tmp/data/
/tmp/data/sub2
/tmp/data/sub2/sub2
/tmp/data/sub2/sub2/foo
/tmp/data/sub2/sub1
/tmp/data/sub2/sub1/foo
/tmp/data/sub2/sub0
/tmp/data/sub2/sub0/foo
/tmp/data/sub1
/tmp/data/sub1/sub2
/tmp/data/sub1/sub2/foo
/tmp/data/sub1/sub1
/tmp/data/sub1/sub1/foo
/tmp/data/sub1/sub0
/tmp/data/sub1/sub0/foo
/tmp/data/sub0
/tmp/data/sub0/sub2
/tmp/data/sub0/sub2/foo
/tmp/data/sub0/sub1
/tmp/data/sub0/sub1/foo
/tmp/data/sub0/sub0
/tmp/data/sub0/sub0/foo

$ cd /tmp/data; tar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar --exclude './sub[1-2]'
./
./sub0/
./sub0/sub2/
./sub0/sub2/foo
./sub0/sub1/
./sub0/sub1/foo
./sub0/sub0/
./sub0/sub0/foo

# ATTENTION: bsdtar's behaviour differs from traditional tar (without a leading '^')!
$ cd /tmp/data; bsdtar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar --exclude './sub[1-2]' .
a .
a ./sub0
a ./sub0/sub0
a ./sub0/sub0/foo

# FIX: Use a regex by adding a leading '^' will cause bsdtar to match only parent files and folders.
$ cd /tmp/data; bsdtar -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar --exclude '^./sub[1-2]' .
# ALTERNATIVE: bsdtar -C /tmp/data -zvcf /tmp/_data.tar --exclude '^./sub[1-2]' .
a .
a ./sub0
a ./sub0/sub2
a ./sub0/sub1
a ./sub0/sub0
a ./sub0/sub0/foo
a ./sub0/sub1/foo
a ./sub0/sub2/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all sorts of combinations including a few of the answers listed and just couldn't get it to exclude the listed files.

So being fed up of chasing the answer to what was meant to be a five minute job I did the opposite: created an archive of the folders I *wanted* to include.

I did this by creating an archive then [adding to it](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-tar-command-examples):

```
tar -cvpf /path/to/mybackup.tar ./bin
tar rvf /path/to/mybackup.tar ./boot
tar rvf /path/to/mybackup.tar ./etc
tar rvf /path/to/mybackup.tar ./home
tar rvf /path/to/mybackup.tar ./lib
tar rvf /path/to/mybackup.tar ./sbin
tar rvf /path/to/mybackup.tar ./usr
tar rvf /path/to/mybackup.tar ./var
```

A few notes:

- I used the relative instead of absolute paths (which were also giving trouble) by running from the root of the filesystem.
- You must create a plain `tar` (and not zipped tar `.tgz` / `.tar.gz`) archive - you can zip it later using `gzip mybackup.tar`
- Make sure you don't put the archive in any folder you are including or you'll get some recursion (a partial backup also included in the backup itself).
- Note the difference in the first command (create) from the others (add).
- You can check that files are being added rather than the backup overwritten (e.g. after the second command) if you are paranoid by using `tar tvf mybackup.tar`.

Answer (score 1):

The `exclude` family of parameters apply to the **internal relative** names of the files in the tarball. The absolute path you specify will never exist within the tarball since it only has relative paths from the provided root.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Perhaps you could add a quote from the `tar` documentation to back up this statement as the other answers seem to contradict. Alternatively, you may want to edit the answer to ensure it is not misunderstood.

Answer (score -1):

**Success Case:**

1) if giving full path to take backup, in exclude also should be used full path.

```
tar -zcvf /opt/ABC/BKP_27032020/backup_27032020.tar.gz \
    --exclude='/opt/ABC/csv/*' --exclude='/opt/ABC/log/*' /opt/ABC
```

2) if giving current path to take backup, in exclude also should be used current path only.

```
tar -zcvf backup_27032020.tar.gz \
    --exclude='ABC/csv/*' --exclude='ABC/log/*' ABC
```

**Failure Case:**

1) if giving currentpath directory to take backup and full path to ignore,then wont work

```
tar -zcvf /opt/ABC/BKP_27032020/backup_27032020.tar.gz \
    --exclude='/opt/ABC/csv/*' --exclude='/opt/ABC/log/*' ABC
```

Note: mentioning exclude before/after backup directory is fine.