# GNU `tar` runs `stat` on an excluded directory. Is it normal?

Tags: tar

I'm running `tar` as **root** like this:

```
cd /
tar --create                    \
    --verify                    \
    --exclude-backups           \
    --exclude-caches            \
    --auto-compress             \
    --file /tmp/home.tar.gz     \
    --exclude=/home/elena/.gvfs \
    home
```

`tar` outputs:

```
tar: home/elena/.gvfs: Cannot stat: Permission denied
```

I would expect the `.gvfs`[1] directory to be ignored completely.  Why is GNU `tar` running `stat` over it?

As to why I'm using `/home/elena/.gvfs` - an absolute path -  to match the `.gvfs` directory, it is because - to my knowledge - there is no other way to select single directories for exclusion without excluding matching subdirectories at any level as well.

I've tried putting the `--exclude` line after `home`, to take possible quirks in different versions of `tar` [into account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32845/19512), but that changes nothing.

Thanks for your attention.

GNU `tar` version: **1.23**

--

[1] `~/.gvfs` is a way to access the [Gnome Virtual File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) I'm skipping it because I know it can't be accessed, and it doesn't make sense to archive it.  I still wonder why `tar` doesn't skip it completely.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home/elena/.gvfs`?

Comment: @MattDMo: I have no idea: even `ls -l /home/elena/.gvfs` as **root** fails because of denied access.  However, I know that `.gvfs` is a way to access the Gnome Virtual File System: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS 

I'm skipping it because I know it can't be accessed, and it doesn't make sense to archive it.

Comment: Try running `ls -al /home/elena` and let us know what the _entire_ `.gvfs` line says. This way, you're not trying to read the contents of `.gvfs` as `ls -l /home/elena/.gvfs` is doing. Also, can you read `/home/elena/.gvfs` as user `elena`, not `root`?

Comment: Run as root, permission denied again:

`ls: cannot access /home/elena/.gvfs: Permission denied`.

And the `.gvfs` line reads:

`d??????????   ? ?    ?         ?            ? .gvfs`

It's the only item in the output of `ls` that looks weird.

Comment: Are those question marks? Sorry, I'm on XP (Firefox 22) and what you posted just showed up as `d?????????? ? ? ? ? ?` (approximately, I just typed that in...)

Comment: could you post a screenshot? This looks really weird...

Answer (score 0):

```
tar: home/elena/.gvfs: Cannot stat: Permission denied
```

Notice that the error message doesn't include a leading slash. Try `--exclude=home/elena/.gvfs` without the slash.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't.  Otherwise the pattern could match subdirectories at every level, and I don't want that.

Comment: Then you can't exclude it.

Comment: Hence `tar` doesn't allow for fine-grained control on what directories and files end up in an archive?

Comment: Not by itself, as far as I understand the documentation. The workaround is to `find | grep - v stuff | xargs tar` or some approximation of that.

Comment: @Elena Try also adding option `--anchored`. Than would match the initial part of the path name even without slash.

Comment: @eppesuig: Thanks, but I can't.  The command in my question is not complete.  The complete version needs to filter files in subdirectories based on their extension, and `--anchored` wouldn't allow that.  Or am I allowed to mix `--anchored` and `--no-anchored` patterns?

Comment: @Elena, yes you can mix `--anchored` and `--no-anchored`.  The [example in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/controlling-pattern_002dmatching.html) uses `--ignore-case`, but it applies to `--anchored` and `--wildcards-match-slash` too.

Comment: @tripleee -- `| tar --files-from - ...` would work as well

Comment: @sendmoreinfo: thanks for the tip; that's better than `xargs` actually.