# Tar --exclude directory isn't being excluded

Tags: tar

Looks like my backup script it's excluding all the directories I've specified except for one `/var/backups` which contains the tar file just created with the script.  What am I doing wrong?

I've already followed the suggestions in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32845/tar-exclude-doesnt-exclude-why).

Here's my script:

```
tar -zcpf /var/backups/"full_system_backup_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).tar.gz" --directory=/ --exclude=/var/backups --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts .
```

Comment: Should --exclude=/var/backups really be --exclude=var/backups ?

Comment: probably so.  because --directory already is set to /........ let me try that and see

Comment: @StephenHarris thanks, your suggestion was spot on.  Mind answering the question so I can accept it?  Or should I just go ahead and answer it myself?

Answer (score 1):

The entry `--exclude=/var/backups` should read `--exclude=var/backups` to match the pattern expected by `tar`